# What is the maximum capacity of a small router?

Tags: linux, networking, router

I developed a Java app, that runs on several Raspberry Pis. This software makes 10 requests to a server at same time during the day. When the first Raspberry was started there wasn't any problem. But when the third Raspberry starts the first one says timeout exception. If I run 50 concurrent queries to a web server with one Raspberry there isn't any problem, but when I use several different machines, the network is going down, and only one raspberry works.

I have a Cisco WR 54 router, 5 Raspberries and 5 PC/Macs.

How can I solve this? Do I have to buy a new and Pro Router or something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most home/soho routers are designed to handle the estimated load associated with 5-10 users, but that figure has a number of assumptions built in, like total bandwidth, number of concurrent connections, etc. years ago I had a pair of roommates that both insisted on running their own torrent clients, and even though each of their throughput was small, the combination of both of them was swamping the TCP handshake tables, and effectively locking the router. Also note, the WRT54G line of routers is really a 2005 era solution, and they got really unreliable as they age. Get something newer.

Comment: If it's your Java program misbehaving buying a new router won't fix it. You need to figure out what is the root cause of the problem. There is not enough information in the question to determine that.

Comment: The software runs ok, I had been testing it several times in different situations, and always respond correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a router problem, it could be that whatever you are accessing on the server becomes 'locked' while one of the pi's queries it.  I'm guessing that running them all from one pi would not be 'concurrent' it would either be sending one large packet for the queries or one right after the other therefore not locking itself out of the server.

You could try a new router but you may be better off trying to manage the traffic to the server file itself.  Setting up a queue or creating a retry cycle for the queries.

Comment: yes, maybe you're right, I considered a possibility at first, but just in case asked if it was Router problem, or what, because sometimes also fell from overcharging. I'll change the program so that a single raspberry perform queries managing network traffic. Thanks!